# How will i get the co-ordinate value from the below JSON using python json into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

{
   "Type" : "type1"
   "Results" : 
   [
     {
       "Type" : "type1"
       "Results" : 
       [
          {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":-0.3,"Value":123123},
          {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":-0.2,"Value":123123},
          {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":-0.1,"Value":123123},
          {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":0,"Value":123123},
          {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":0.1,"Value":123123},
          {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":0.2,"Value":123123},
          {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":0.3,"Value":123123}
       ]
     }
   ]
}

Comment: This  question is similar to [Python Multilevel Json to Pandas data frame with index and extraction third level data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025621/python-multilevel-json-to-pandas-data-frame-with-index-and-extraction-third-leve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `JSON` you have posted is not valid `JSON`. The correct version is

```
{
    "Type" : "type1",
    "Results" :
        [
            { "Type" : "type1", "Results" :
             [
                 {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":-0.3,"Value":123123},
                 {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":-0.2,"Value":123123},
                 {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":-0.1,"Value":123123},
                 {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":0,"Value":123123},
                 {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":0.1,"Value":123123},
                 {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":0.2,"Value":123123}, 
                 {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":0.3,"Value":123123} 
             ] 
            } 
        ] 
}
```

Please note the missing **,** that are missing in you post. I don't know exactly what you want, but please have a look at the following.

```py
import pandas as pd

json = {
    "Type" : "type1",
    "Results" :
        [
            { "Type" : "type1", "Results" :
             [
                 {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":-0.3,"Value":123123},
                 {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":-0.2,"Value":123123},
                 {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":-0.1,"Value":123123},
                 {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":0,"Value":123123},
                 {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":0.1,"Value":123123},
                 {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":0.2,"Value":123123}, 
                 {"Type":"type1","Coordinate":0.3,"Value":123123} 
             ] 
            } 
        ] 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(json["Results"][0]["Results"])
```

which gives you

```
    Type    Coordinate  Value
0   type1   -0.3        123123
1   type1   -0.2        123123
2   type1   -0.1        123123
3   type1   0.0         123123
4   type1   0.1         123123
```

Comment: pd.DataFrame(json["Results"][0]["Results"]) : this one worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d = json.load(open('results.json'))
>>> d['Results'][0]['Results'][0]['Coordinate']
-0.3
>>> d['Results'][0]['Results'][1]['Coordinate']
-0.2
```

You can iterate through those,
or simply pass pandas that final `Results`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d['Results'][0]['Results'])
>>> df.dtypes
Type           object
Coordinate    float64
Value           int64
```

You apparently intended to use the following JSON input,
which is a little different from what you posted.

```
{"Results": [{"Results": [{"Coordinate": -0.3, "Type": "type1", "Value": 123123},
                          {"Coordinate": -0.2, "Type": "type1", "Value": 123123},
                          {"Coordinate": -0.1, "Type": "type1", "Value": 123123},
                          {"Coordinate": 0, "Type": "type1", "Value": 123123},
                          {"Coordinate": 0.1, "Type": "type1", "Value": 123123},
                          {"Coordinate": 0.2, "Type": "type1", "Value": 123123},
                          {"Coordinate": 0.3, "Type": "type1", "Value": 123123}],
              "Type": "type1"}],
 "Type": "type1"}
```